# why doesn't python return booleans

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this small function that takes two integers `a` and `b` and checks if `a` is `b` raised to some exponent. This is the code.

```
def is_power(a,b):

    if not a%b==0:
        return a%b==0

    elif a/b==1:
       return a/b==1

    else:
        a = a/b
        is_power(a,b)

print is_power(,)
```

The problem is that this always returns `None` no matter what I input.

But if I replace all returns with prints, then they give the correct result, i.e. `True` or `False`.

```
def is_power(a,b):

    if not a%b==0:
        print a%b==0

    elif a/b==1:
       print a/b==1

    else:
        a = a/b
        is_power(a,b)

is_power(,)
```

Why does this happen? This is probably a noob question, but I still can't think it out.
Thanks

Comment: Are you missing a `return` on the last line of the function?

Comment: Yes he is missing a return statement. Also, are you calling the function with no arguments, or were the arguments relatives of Harry Houdini?

Comment: @JohnDoe: No the function is not without arguments. I simply didn't put any values in there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are ignoring the return value of the recursive call, add a `return` there:

```
else:
    a = a/b
    return is_power(a,b)
```

Without the `return` statement there, your function just ends and returns `None` instead. The return value of the recursive call is otherwise ignored.

With the `return` statement, your code works:

```
>>> def is_power(a,b):
...     if not a%b==0:
...         return a%b==0
...     elif a/b==1:
...        return a/b==1
...     else:
...         a = a/b
...         return is_power(a, b)
... 
>>> print is_power(10, 3)
False
>>> print is_power(8, 2)
True
```

Comment: Thanks, it does indeed work if I add a return in the last else clause. But I'm still having a little trouble in understanding the flow of execution. If 'a' is a power of 'b' then eventually it'll reach the second clause which has a return statement. And if it isn't then it'll stop at the first if clause which again returns a False. In either case the function ends at one of the first two clauses which each return a value. Why should that 'return' be inserted before the function call in the last else clause? Thanks for the patience

Comment: @Mishrito: You are forgetting that when `is_power()` calls itself, and that call returns, control returns to the previous invocation of `is_power()`, **not** to whatever called the first `is_power()` function. So in your `else` block at the end, control returns to that point when the recursive `is_power()` call is done. At that point, your code discards whatever the recursive call returned. The function ends there, and `None` is returned, effectively ignoring the recursive call result.

Comment: Ah understood. Thanks for the explanation. I'm trying to teach myself python and sometimes it can get tough to wrap my head around such things. Again thanks for the patience

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to return on the last else clause.